# Show sum of different comboboxes shown in textboxes into one textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, textbox

I want the total value of different values I selected from different comboboxes which are shown in there own textbox.

```
 private void tbWater1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(tbWater1 is null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbWater1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbWater2.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbMais.Text))
                tbTotaal.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tbWater1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(tbWater2.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(tbMais.Text)).ToString();
        }
        
    }
```

This is what I have so far for one textboxes which shows the value of a combobox but it doesn't show the total sum into the textbox I want the total sum of those in.

Any tips?

Comment: `if(tbWater1 is null)` => `if(tbWater1 != null)`

Answer (score 0):

You will never enter first `if` block, since `tbWater1_TextChanged` is an event handler of `tbWater1` and hence `tbWater1` is not `null` if it being called.

You can remove the outer `if` and leave just:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbWater1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbWater2.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbMais.Text))
{
    tbTotaal.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tbWater1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(tbWater2.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(tbMais.Text)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: If I leave the outer `if` out, I get an error saying that the objectreference is not set on a copy of a object

Comment: I can't follow you. Which copy? If you use the same event handler for several comboboxes, then leave the outer `if` statement with check `tbWater1` is not null: `if(tbWater1 != null)` Also please take a minute and read about [**M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).